# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'retrieveMultiple' of undefined

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to run a JavaScript on an HTML page in CRM 9.0 which is giving me following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'retrieveMultiple' of
>   undefined

I have just migrated my solution from CRM 8.2 to CRM 9.0 everything was working fine in CRM 8.2, even when i run the same page in CRM 8.2 environment it runs fine but in CRM 9.0 it is giving me above error.
Also, I when i run the same page from within inside CRM 9.0, it works fine. Only when i run this page through on web using a URL it gives this error.
I do not understand why this error is coming,

I am using below code where error is coming,

```
 XrmSvcToolkit.retrieveMultiple({
    entityName: SpecialOperationEntity,  //Update this code later
    odataQuery: Query,
    async: false,
    successCallback: successCallback,
    errorCallback: errorCallback
});
```

**EDIT:**

The image taken is from the console. Why is the XrmSvcToolkit error coming I am not sure. Can anyone please guide? As the reference is available in HTML page

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

For all those that are suggesting me to use Web.API

When I am using Web Api and comment out this current logic the actual js file does not even load inside HTML and the HTML file gives an error where it says that it cannot find the functions defined in js file (because the js file did not load in this case).

I am using below code,

```
 Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords(SpecialOperationEntity, "$select=vrp_Output&$filter=vrp_Operation eq '" + Operation + "' and vrp_Input eq '" + JsonInputParameter + "'";).then(
       successCallback
        ,errorCallback
    );
```

**Note:**
successCallback and errorCallback are two functions defined below this code block

Comment: XrmSvcToolkit seems not defined

Comment: It is defined in the HTML Page

Comment: Could you update your question ? show in console what you have in XrmSvcToolkit and let us know when XrmSvcToolkit is initialize

Comment: console log the object. Then see if the retrieveMultiple property is in the property list.

Comment: I have just checked in console and it is showing XrmSvcToolkit as undefined

Comment: The question has been edited

Comment: How do you import the library? maybe it is the problem

Comment: When I run the same page from CRM it does not give me any error.

Comment: Could link the library you load ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using 9.0 why not just move to WebAPI.
I would highly recomend using WebAPI for doing retrieveMultiple
Using Webapi is really easy and you do not need any external 3rd party libaray into system as well.
Take a Look at [CRM Rest Builder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder) its really simple to build Webapi queries.

Sample code for RetreiveMultipe

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/accounts?$select=accountclassificationcode,accountid&$filter=accountid eq 123456789", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
            for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++) {
                var accountclassificationcode = results.value[i]["accountclassificationcode"];
                var accountclassificationcode_formatted = results.value[i]["accountclassificationcode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
                var accountid = results.value[i]["accountid"];
            }
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```

Comment: Can you please check the latest edit I made in my question

Answer (score 1):

You should consider switching to Xrm.WebApi since XrmSvcToolkit is an outdated 3rd-party tool. This is how you can retrieve multiple records since Dynamics 365 v9:

```
        Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("account", "?$select=name").then(
            function success(result) {
                // perform additional operations on retrieved records
            },
            function (error) {
                // handle error conditions
            }
        );
```

You can check the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/retrievemultiplerecords).

**EDIT**

If you want to do a call to Xrm WebApi **inside** your HTML IFRAME you have to prefix it with `window.parent`, so any call to Xrm WebApi would start with `window.parent.Xrm.WebApi`.

If you want to access a JS function that is defined **outside** your HTML IFRAME you have to prefix it with `parent.frames[0]`, so a call to a function called SomeFunction would be `parent.frames[0].SomeFunction()`.

Comment: Can you please check the latest edit I made in my question

Answer (score 1):

Like other answers recommended, you have to switch to `Xrm.Webapi` methods for Asynchronous processing or `XMLHttpRequest` for Synchronous/Asynchronous calls. CRM REST Builder is vital.

I will answer your question:

> Only when i run this page through on web using a URL it gives this error. I do not understand why this error is coming,

You might have added the script file reference in HTML page like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vrp_franix_XrmSvcToolKit.js"></script>
```

This might be broken. Also console errors suggest `CRM context is not available` and other errors like `Cannot read property Page of undefined` means this HTML can be used only in CRM context & needed a lot of plumbing. [Read this community thread.](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/199908)

Better retire this library & remediate the code to use Product recommended features.

**Update**:

If you want to use **Xrm** in HTML web resource the you have to refer the context from parent CRM window.

If HTML page is embedded in form:

```
window.parent.Xrm.WebApi
```

If HTML page is opened in popup:

```
window.opener.Xrm.WebApi
```

Comment: I am referencing it like this   <script language="javascript" src="../Common/js/vrp_franix_XrmSvcToolkit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

I have read the community thread and it says the same thing. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: @FaranSaleem when you open the html page, view the source from right click & click the above link in html header in source.. if it’s not accessible - fix the url.